# 24GHz Mixer - How to shift the frequency of a 24GHz(100MHz bandwidth) signal by +-4kHz

Tags: rf, modulation, demodulation, mixer, radar

Why do I want this? When a 24GHz radar signal hits an object that has a relative velocity, the frequency of the signal will shift by a frequency on the order of kilohertz. I want to create this process of frequency shift electronically.

I receive a 24GHz(100MHz bandwidth) signal from the antenna. I want to shift the frequency by something on the order of kilohertz (from -4kHz to +4kHz).

(the carrier signal is 24GHz, I want to turn it into what it would have been, had the carrier frequency been 24.000004Ghz)

I have a few ideas:

(+4kHz here is just an example, it could be anything between -4kHz and +4kHz)

Using [this](https://www.hittite.com/content/documents/data_sheet/hmc1063lp3e.pdf).

[image]

I will put the received signal to LO. Put cos(2pi 4kHz t) and -sin(2pi 4kHz t) to IF1 and IF2 ports. Does this have any chance of working? Would it cause problems to put a 100MHz bandwidth signal to a LO port?

Another idea is: I can demodulate it by, say 20GHz. Put 20GHz to the IQ modulator I posted above and shift it above by putting cos(2pi 4kHz t) and -sin(2pi 4kHz t) into IF1 and IF2. And then modulating the signal by 20.000004GHz.

Comment: Move fast? ....

Comment: Are your signals and oscillators even stable within that frequency range?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Frequency-shifting a signal by 0.2 ppm seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: @AdamHaun When talking about radar applications, it would not be odd at all :-)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I need the oscillators to remain coherent for 80ms. I am not concerned by the received signal. I assume the received signal is proper.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Wow! That's pretty hardcore!

Comment: Not sure what your application is but you could probably get some ideas by opening up a bunch of older radar speed jamming devices.  I also expect that the new radar speed testing guns will be immune to such Doppler modification.  You may find it ignores the return frequency and uses a code chirp that it correlates after demodulation.

Answer (score 3):

Note that this "GaAs MMIC I/Q MIXER" is, to put it bluntly, basically just a couple of fast diodes in a package !

"I will put the received signal to LO.... Does this have any chance of working?" Yes if your received signal is strong enough. Note that on the datasheet, first page above the table it says: LO = + 10 dBm
If your received signal is less than that, it might not work.

"Would it cause problems to put a 100MHz bandwidth signal to a LO port?"
Not as long as that 100 MHz is within the 21 - 30 GHz range.
On page 12 there's a schematic of the LO input, note that it is AC coupled and that there is an inductor. These are tuned to that 21 -30 GHz range so any signal outside that range will not be able to get in as the input is not tuned for that.

You mean that you want to frequency shift your received signal by 4 kHz by applying 4 kHz quadrature signals at the IF inputs, 24 GHz (BW = 100 MHz) at the LO input and then have the resulting 24.000004 GHz at the RF output ? That might work but I would start by applying the Received signal at the RF input instead if the LO. And even then I doubt whether the frequency shift will happen and if it does, if it will have enough conversion gain.

This module looks like a downconversion mixer to me so maybe it is not what you need.

Why don't you look for a module from for example [MiniCircuits](http://194.75.38.69/homepage/homepage.html), Skyworks, Tryquint or Avago which is more suitable for this task ?

Comment: That was very helpful, however I do not fully understand what kind of modules would be more suitable for this. Also the reasonI want to put the received signal to LO is because the only components that allowed the received signal to be +20GHz were demodulators.

Comment: After reading Dave's answer I agree that shifting a 24 GHz, 100 MHz BW  signal by 4 kHz is not an endeavor that is very likely to succeed. You mentioned that you are new to this area. Combined with the fact that anything above 1 GHz is not for the uninitiated I suggest you have a look at some literature and see how these things are done.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to shift a signal by a tiny amount that's within its own bandwidth is virtually impossible to do with a single stage. The problem is that mixers are far from perfect, with not only the sum and difference signals appearing at the output, but also a significant amount of the original input signals. In most applications, these unwanted signals are removed by post-filtering, but that can only work if their spectra don't overlap.

In other words, what you're trying to do will almost certainly require at least two stages of conversion, one to shift the signal by more than 100 MHz, and another to shift it back by whatever the first shift was ±4 kHz.

(It's possible that this is what you were saying in the last part of your question, but it wasn't at all clear what you meant.)

Comment: I also had this idea: I can demodulate it by, say 20GHz. Put 20GHz to the IQ modulator I posted above and shift it above by putting cos(2pi 4kHz t) and -sin(2pi 4kHz t) into IF1 and IF2. And then modulating the signal by 20.000004GHz. So I use 2 regular mixers and 1 quadrature mixer?

Comment: You are using standard terms in nonstandard ways. "Demodulate" means to reduce a signal to baseband; "modulate" is the opposite process. What you seem to be describing is more like the double conversion that I was talking about, with a 4 GHz IF. I don't know why you'd need a third mixer, though, unless you're using it to generate the 20.000004 GHz second LO signal from the 20.000000 GHz first LO.

Comment: I am sorry for my incorrect terminology, unfortunately I am quite inexperienced. I call it 'demodulate' because usually demodulators take in a high frequency signal and high frequency LO. "I don't know why you'd need a third mixer". Yes, I figured that it would be impossible to have two 20GHz signals with 4kHz difference unless one of them were created from the other. What are the standard names for the components I am looking for? Mathematically all I want to do is multiply and add some signals, but with real life components at 24GHz, it gets far more intricate than that.

Comment: Yes, it does get very intricate, and there's probably a better approach. Please add a higher-level description of what you're trying to accomplish overall to your question, and maybe we can offer suggestions that avoid the need for such a strange conversion in the first place.

Comment: When a 24GHz radar signal hits an object that has a relative velocity, the frequency of the signal will shift by a frequency on the order of kilohertz. I want to create this process of frequency shift electronically.

Comment: You mean Doppler shift ;-) We create such a signal by putting a reflector on a cart on a rail and moving it with a certain speed :-) If we would have been able to do that electronically, we probably would have done that (also). But our radar is at 60 GHz so the shift is larger at a lower speed.